# External link to existing Microsoft Teams chat

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have developed a Microsoft Teams app, and I'm using 'deep linking' to create named chats (chats with topic names) with selected users, as per the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat

An example of a 'deep link' to create a chat would be:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com,dave@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow

This works fine - and if I save the portion of the link minus the 'message' portion, this again works fine, and links the user to the existing chat:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com,dave@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow

However, if another user is added to the chat from inside Teams itself, the link above will not link to the existing chat any more, rather create a brand new chat instance with the same topicName and originally specified users.

Is there a way of 'deep linking' to a chat by it's topicName or some kind of ID only? Without having to get clever with the Microsoft Graph API?

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow
just links to the chat 'home screen', where a user can start a new chat through Teams

Comment: Can you let us know if your issue is resolved yet?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't achieve this directly. As soon as you add a new person, it's no longer the "same" chat, so to speak (e.g. a chat with "Joe, Bob and Dave" is NOT the same as a chat with "Joe, Bob, Dave and Sue". The two ways I can think of that you *can* achieve what you're looking for though, are:

1. create a *Meeting* with that subject - the "meeting" chat seems to hang around forever, it has a title, and you can modify participants, even after the "meeting" is over.
2. Alternative to the above, if there's an ongoing initiative, maybe it's just better as an actual Team or Channel anyway...?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I'll look into using Meetings for this purpose later. One thing I did think of just after I posted this was to link to a search for the conversation topicName. 

Linking into Teams with the search bar highlighted using; https://teams.microsoft.com/l/search

However I can't work out how to pre-fill the search bar?

I tried: 

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/search?text=test, https://teams.microsoft.com/l/search?q=test, https://teams.microsoft.com/l/search?query=test, etc. - can't find any official docs on this - any idea?

Comment: Also my customer has specifically said they do not wish to have hundreds of teams and or channels - but a good shout nevertheless

Comment: Did you give the Meeting option a go?

Comment: I just had a go - the same problem applies with creating a link back to the existing meeting (or the associated chat). https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new endpoint seems to be supported - but I can't find an equivalent https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/edit or /update. The link to the meeting in the calendar event itself contains some crazy uuid which I guess you would need to use the graph API to access [https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_ZDRhNmI4NzAtNzQ...]

Comment: that "19:..." might be useful... I've got a link like the following, to an existing meeting: https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/19:meeting_[Long value]@thread.v2?ctx=chat . Try do the same with your link, and you might be able to basically get a deeplink. Incidentally, I notice your sample link actually includes a querystring parameter called "deeplinkid", that might also be useful

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around I got this working link (also for Teams 2.0):

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/19:aeba3eb87af1234567890abc54321@thread.v2
(ChatID [19:...] can be fetched with Power Automate or using the browsers dev console)

This sends users, who are already part of the group chat, directly to the chat (with a reroute via browser). Users, who are not part of the chat, get an error message.

Answer (score -2):

I came here looking a solution to this same requirement.. a link that others can click on to dial into a normal MS Teams (multi-person) chat. I want to include this in my meeting invites in the case where I initially created the chat group manually within MS Teams (not originally via meeting invite).
I opened the chat in MS Teams Web (in my browser) to get the unique conversation identifier and then replaced that portion in a sample link that I would typically find in meeting invites. I also removed the context parameter. When I followed the resulting link in my browser it launched my MS Teams desktop application and joined the chat group meeting. An illustrative sample link is below:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/*19:1235774810bf4d7086ada8e13c7c6c8a@thread.v2/0*

The portion "19:1235774810bf4d7086ada8e13c7c6c8a@thread.v2/0" is what I replaced.
And there is no need for something like "?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%22c9b9cb50-3544-4db4-a267-fa84df2f4ceb%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22663db54f-657a-407d-8a0b-45c76d8cdffd%22%7d" at the end either. I'm not sure what will happen if someone uses this link who has not been added to the chat by me though. You'll have to test that if that is a requirement.

Comment: This link doesn't seem to work